# Is it possible to scaffold a dbcontext without any models?

Tags: entity-framework-core, scaffolding

Note: This is for Core 3.0

I'm creating a project that uses an existing DB and all interaction is through existing stored procedures.  Therefore, I don't need to generate entity models.

I understand how to scaffold and create entity models for all tables and specific tables but I can't find any documentation for no tables.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this helping ?
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx It's stored procedure with DB-First, just made for EF 6.

Comment: No.  I need something that works with Core 3 not Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

With EF Core this is currently not possible, the scaffolding is based on tables and views.